# install grub after copy ubuntu

Tags: boot, clone

i need to install grub on a new hard drive.

i have a 1tb hard drive with linux mint on it.

i also have a dual boot 40gb hard drive with windows xp and ubuntu 12.04lts with grub to chose an os.

i want to copy the ubuntu install from the 40 gb drive on to the bigger drive i have done this already (http://paste.ubuntu.com/7465749/)

i have copied the ubuntu install and put it on the new hard drive with linux mint already on it using gparted in linux mint.

so after i have done this how can i install grub on the 1tb drive to chose an os at boot ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to remove the old 40GB hdd, you should ensure that GRUB and `/boot` partition are installed onto the second drive. There is good instruction in [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Alternatively, you can use [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)'s Recommended repair. It will place GRUB on all drives.

However, Linux Mint uses GRUB too, and if you put the GRUB onto 1TB drive (`/dev/sdb`) when you did install it, you just need to boot into Mint and run `sudo update-grub`. It should print that it found Ubuntu.

**Resume**: check if Mint starts from the second hdd, and if it will, just run `sudo update-grub` in it. If not, use Boot Repair or install GRUB manually.

Comment: The update-grub should fix most of it. I have had troubles with Boot Repair always working (when installing GRUB on all the drives/partitions) If it doesn't work it may actually be better to install GRUB manually if Boot-Repair doesn't work(Link follows). https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing